# Vector Tutorials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I'm looking for some basic information about vector before going through a chapter in book. Can someone provide links to some good tutorials?

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze book on Linear Algebra is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search on Google gives this page as a first hit: http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/vcalc.html

Is there anything in specific you'd like some info on?

Comment: I'd like know what topics do i need to be covered to start reading about vector. Thanks.

Comment: I think that depends on the course you're going to follow. If it's an introductory course I think you're going to be fine if you have knowledge on some basic real analysis (and participate in the course, ofcourse).